# I get 500 error when I upload an existing image

Tags: java, image, apache, jsp, servlets

I am unable to upload images into my database using servlets, I get the below error.

```
HTTP Status 500 - troubleshoot.png (No such file or directory)

type Exception report
message troubleshoot.png (No such file or directory)   
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: troubleshoot.png (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
ActionObject.Input.doGet(Input.java:54)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.
```

This is my code:

```
input class="filestyle" type="file" name="photo" size="10"  
required="required" accept="image/*">
```

My web.xml file has this:

```
<context-param>
      <param-name>tempfile.dir</param-name>
      <param-value>tmpfiles</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Java code that sets the image name as a file:

```
 st.setPic(new FileInputStream(new File(request.getParameter("photo"))));
```

Comment: if thats your actual code then you have 2 type attribute in input field

Comment: @singhakash Fixed it, same error.

Comment: have you tryed uploading other image

Comment: @divinediu Have you solved the issue , post your form code ?

Comment: Still unable to upload image